Spring Cloud Kubernetes Leader Election: different leaders for different functionalities
My goal was to achieve that only 1 pod of my application executes a scheduled job.
I have implemented a following simple example using kubernetes election leader functionality and it works:
1.Maven dependencies:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-leader</artifactId>
</dependency>

2.application.yaml:
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      leader:
        enabled: true
        autoStartup: true

3.Code with @Scheduled job:
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.integration.leader.event.OnGrantedEvent;
import org.springframework.integration.leader.event.OnRevokedEvent;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Log4j2
@Component
public class ScheduledJob {

    private boolean isLeader = false;

    @EventListener(OnGrantedEvent.class)
    public void onLeaderGranted(OnGrantedEvent event) {
        log.info("Leadership granted to this instance.");
        isLeader = true;
    }

    @EventListener(OnRevokedEvent.class)
    public void onLeaderRevoked(OnRevokedEvent event) {
        log.info("Leadership revoked from this instance.");
        isLeader = false;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void foo() {
        if (isLeader) {
            log.info("I am foo leader.");
        } else {
            log.info("Skipping foo because I'm not the leader.");
        }
    }
}

Now I want to implement a scenario where different pods run different scheduled jobs, with each pod being responsible for running its own job, so pod-1 can be leader to run job-1, pod-2 for job-2.
Job 1:
@Log4j2
@Component
public class ScheduledJob1 {

    private boolean isLeader = false;

    @EventListener(OnGrantedEvent.class)
    public void onLeaderGranted(OnGrantedEvent event) {
        log.info("Leadership for ScheduledJob1 granted to this instance.");
        isLeader = true;
    }

    @EventListener(OnRevokedEvent.class)
    public void onLeaderRevoked(OnRevokedEvent event) {
        log.info("Leadership for ScheduledJob1 revoked from this instance.");
        isLeader = false;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void foo1() {
        if (isLeader) {
            log.info("I am foo 1 leader.");
        } else {
            log.info("Skipping foo 1 because I'm not the leader.");
        }
    }
}

Job 2:
@Log4j2
@Component
public class ScheduledJob2 {

    private boolean isLeader = false;

    @EventListener(OnGrantedEvent.class)
    public void onLeaderGranted(OnGrantedEvent event) {
        log.info("Leadership for ScheduledJob2 granted to this instance");
        isLeader = true;
    }

    @EventListener(OnRevokedEvent.class)
    public void onLeaderRevoked(OnRevokedEvent event) {
        log.info("Leadership for ScheduledJob2 revoked from this instance.");
        isLeader = false;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void foo2() {
        if (isLeader) {
            log.info("I am foo2 leader.");
        } else {
            log.info("Skipping foo2 because I'm not the leader.");
        }
    }
}

How can I achieve this?
Probably with different roles, but I don't understand how to set up them...
If you need any clarification, let me know, thank you in advance!

I'm still reading to properly understand your question, but a minor heads up in the time being. We will be deprecating and eventually removing this implementation that you are using in favor of : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/pull/1658 . Its not yet merged and no ETA for now, but just be prepared for the future

you're right in the sense that this could probably be supported with an array of roles, but currently, there is no way to achieve this, at least in my understanding and knowledge of the code. We could undergo some changes and support such a thing, but this will only be seen as an enhancement. You can open an issue on the git page and may be we will pick it up in the future. thank you

Usually in such cases you leader appoint lieutenant to do his jobs for him.
So leader should get all the gang and distribute task between them. Then call them using, for example, REST and tell them to do tasks.

Thanks for the answer! It seems a bit like a workaround to me :) I would try to go a bit along the lines described in this question, but I can't figure out how to create this logic to set up leaders for different roles.
